# A string value read from a toml file contains extra quotation marks

Tags: rust, toml

A string value read from a toml file contains extra quotation marks:

```
  # Toml file
  string_key = "fdsafdsafdsfds"
```

Code:

```
let cfg_file_content = get_config_file_content();
let cfg_data: Value = toml::from_str(&cfg_file_content).expect("failed to parse toml");
cfg_data.as_table().unwrap();

//1
let val1 = cfg_data.get("string_key").unwrap();

// ====> \""fdsafdsafdsfds\""
// or String("fdsafdsafdsfds")



//2
let val = format!("value is: {}", val1);
println!("{:?}", val);

// ====> "value is: \"fdsafdsafdsfds\""
```

How to remove these additional quotation marks?

Crate:

```
toml = "0.4.5"
```

Answer (score 5):

`val1` is the [Value](http://alexcrichton.com/toml-rs/toml/value/enum.Value.html) enum of toml, you need to transform it to str:

```
let val = format!("value is: {}", val1.as_str().unwrap());
```

But, you should use [serde](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/index.html) crate that will do the work for you.

For exemple:

```
extern crate toml;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    string_key: String,
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = toml::from_str("string_key = \"fdsafdsafdsfds\"").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", foo);

    // or
    use std::collections::BTreeMap;
    let foo: BTreeMap<String, String> = toml::from_str("string_key = \"fdsafdsafdsfds\"").unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", foo);
}
```

Comment: instead of just calling ".as_str()" I should use the crate for this?